# How do I export a single site in a multisite content without using a plugin? The default WP export does not catch all

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite, and I would like to export one of my subsites into a standalone WP installation. I do not want to use a plugin for this, Is there any known step-by-step documentation to follow, please?

Comment: The default WP export does not catch all what? What's missing?

Comment: Why not a plugin? eg https://github.com/10up/MU-Migration